# Problem freeing memory from multidimensional array in C, free() crashes program

Tags: c

I am creating a deque to store stings in C, and when I call the free() function, the program crashes.  I have implemented a similar structure but only storing integers, and encountered no problems, but this seems to be causing me a few. I created a struct containing a multidimensional array or characters, and i think maybe I am not using the pointers correctly? I have searched far and wide and cannot solve it The main area of concern is when i call clear() from the ain body. That in turn calls free(), and the program just stalls. :-( Any help would be extremely useful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 20 // number of characters for word

typedef struct {
  char **deque;
  int   size;
  int pFront;
  int pRear;
} deque;

typedef int bool;
enum { false, true };

void initDeque(deque *d, int initialSize) 
{
  d->size = initialSize;
  d->pFront = -1;
  d->pRear = -1;
  d->deque = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*initialSize);
  int idx;
  for(int idx = 0; idx < d->size; idx++)
  {
    d->deque[idx] = (char *)malloc((MAX+1) * sizeof(char));
    d->deque[idx] = "";
  } 
  printf("d->size: %zu\n", d->size);
}

void clear(deque *d) {
  if(d->pFront == -1)
  {
    printf("Queue is empty\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Attempting to clear...\n");
    for(int idx = 0; idx < d->size; idx++)
    {
      printf("Attempting to clear columns...");
      free(d->deque[idx]);
    }
    printf("Attempting to clear rows...");
    free(d->deque);
    printf("Freed!!!!\n");
    d->deque = NULL;
    d->size = 0;
    d->pFront = -1;
    d->pRear = -1;
  } 
}


bool isEmpty(deque *d)
{
  if(d->pFront == -1){
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
bool isFull(deque *d)
{
  if(d->size == d->pRear+1)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

void display(deque *d)
{
  if(isEmpty(d)){
    printf("empty\n");
  }
  else{
    printf("Deque Values:\n");
    int idx;
    for(int idx = 0; idx <= d->pRear; idx++)
    {
      printf("Index: %zu\tValue: %s\n", idx, d->deque[idx]);
    } 
    printf("Size: %zu\n", d->size);
  } 
}
void rAppend(deque *d, char item[]) // as in rear append - same enqueue for queue structure.
{ 
  if(isFull(d))
  {
    printf("Is Full\n");
    int idx;
    deque dTemp;
    initDeque(&dTemp, d->size);
    printf("dTemp Initialised\n");
    for(idx = 0; idx < d->size; idx++)
    {
      dTemp.deque[idx] = d->deque[idx];
    }
    printf("deque copied to dTemp:\n");
    for(idx = 0; idx < d->size; idx++)
    {
      printf("dTemp[%zu]: %s\n", idx, dTemp.deque[idx]);
    }
    clear(&d);
    printf("d cleared\n");
    initDeque(&d, dTemp.size*2);
    printf("New deque of double length initialised\n");
    for(idx = 0; idx < dTemp.size; idx++)
    {
      d->deque[idx] = d->deque[idx];
    }
    printf("dTemp Copied to new deque\n");
    clear(&dTemp);
    printf("dTemp Cleared\n");
    char **tmp = realloc( d->deque, sizeof (d->deque) * (d->size*2) );
    if (tmp)
    {
        d->deque = tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < d->size; i++)
        {   
            d->deque[d->size + i] = malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX );
        }
    }
  }
  printf("Appending to rear.. %s\n", item);
  d->pRear++;
  d->deque[d->pRear] = item;
  if(d->pFront == -1)
      d->pFront = 0;
}
int main(void)
{
    deque d;
    initDeque(&d, 5);
    rAppend(&d, "when");
    rAppend(&d, "will");
    rAppend(&d, "wendy");
    rAppend(&d, "walk");
    rAppend(&d, "with");
    display(&d);
    clear(&d);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: May you try to run this under a debugger ?

Comment: FYI, I built a tool to report segfault, here is a test of your code: https://segfault.stensal.com/a/ye6MfSt2IB0PlJUc,  it reports freeing a global const variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your are calling free() on static chain "when", "will",...

You can replace insertion in the function `void rAppend(deque *d, char item[])` :

```
  d->deque[d->pRear] = item;
```

with:

```
  d->deque[d->pRear] = strdup(item);
```

Doing like this chains are allocated in the heap and free from the heap.
After there is others problems in the code, but it run without crash.

Comment: That was it thanks so much! I haven't used since since my first year so I need to get my head round pointers. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be that you don't appreciate the difference between copying / assigning *pointers* and copying / assigning *the data to which they point*.  Secondarily, it seems you may not appreciate the utility of pointers that don't point to anything, especially null pointers.  Some details follow.

---

You are dynamically allocating space for a bunch of strings ...

> ```
>   for(int idx = 0; idx < d->size; idx++)
>   {
>     d->deque[idx] = (char *)malloc((MAX+1) * sizeof(char));
> ```

...  and then leaking all of that space by replacing the pointer to each with a pointer to an empty string literal:

> ```
>     d->deque[idx] = "";
>   }
> ```

As if the leak were not bad enough, you are not permitted to free a string literal or modify its content, which you nevertheless try to do to any of those pointers that remain in the dequeue whenever you `clear()` it.  This is likely the cause of some of your errors.

If you want to set each allocated string to an empty one then modify its *content* instead of replacing the pointer to it.  For example:

```
    d->deque[idx][0] = '\0';
```

In fact, however, you probably don't need to do even that.  You are already performing bookkeeping to know which arrays contain valid (string) data and which don't, and that should be sufficient to do the right thing.  Supposing you maintain copies of the strings in the first place.

But that's not all.  When you `rAppend()` elements to your deque you have a similar problem.  You create a temporary deque, and then copy the string *pointers* from your original deque into the temporary:

> ```
> dTemp.deque[idx] = d->deque[idx];
> ```

Not only does this leak the original (empty) data in the temporary deque, it aliases that deque's contents with the main deque's.  When you later clear the temporary deque, therefore, you free all the string pointers in the original.  Subsequently using or freeing them produces undefined behavior.

Perhaps you instead want to `strcpy()` all the elements of the main deque into the temp and back, but I suggest instead skipping the temp deque altogether with something along these lines:

```
void rAppend(deque *d, char item[]) // as in rear append - same enqueue for queue structure.
{ 
  if(isFull(d))
  {
    printf("Is Full\n");
    char **tmp = realloc(d.deque, d->size * 2);

    if (tmp)
    {
        d->deque = tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < d->size; i++)
        {   
            // Copied from the original, but see below
            d->deque[d->size + i] = malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX );
        }
        d->size * 2;
    }  // else?
  }
  printf("Appending to rear.. %s\n", item);
  d->pRear++;
  // Oops, this is another leak / aliasing issue:
  d->deque[d->pRear] = item;
  if(d->pFront == -1)
      d->pFront = 0;
}
```

The whole point of the temporary deque is lost on me, since the `realloc()` you need to do preserves the original data anyway (as long as it succeeds, anyway).

Note too, however, that this still has an aliasing issue: you have aliased a deque element with the appended string, and leaked the memory allocated for that element.  Furthermore, when you clear the deque, you free that string for everyone holding a pointer to it.  Or at least you attempt to do so.  You're not permitted to do that to string literals.

I suggest not allocating space in your deque for the individual strings at all, and not freeing it.  Continue to use assignment to store elements in your deque, understanding and embracing that these are aliases.  This will be more analogous to your implementation for `int`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comprehensive reply. It has helped me to understand where a lot of my problems are coming from, I need to do some more work with pointers. thank again!

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct S {
    S() { cout << "make an S\n"; }
    ~S() { cout << "destroy an S\n"; }
    S(const S&) { cout << "copy initialize an S\n"; }
    S& operator=(const S&) { cout << "copy assign an S\n"; }
};
S* f()
{
    return new S;   // who is responsible for deleting this S?
};
unique_ptr<S> g()
{
    return make_unique<S>();    // explicitly transfer responsibility for deleting this S
}
int main()
{
    cout << "start main\n";
    S* p = f();
    cout << "after f() before g()\n";
//  S* q = g(); // this error would be caught by the compiler
    unique_ptr<S> q = g();
    cout << "exit main\n";
    // leaks *p
    // implicitly deletes *q
}
```